# Spark filter not working as expected.. 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When using the "and" clause in filter on Spark Dataframe, it returns `Spark.SQL.Column` instead of `Spark Dataframe`. But for one condition it works fine.

How to `show()` or iterate through Spark Sql Column object?
When tried `show()` function is throws error - `'Column' object not callable.`

Or how does one convert `Spark.SQL.Column` to Spark Dataframe? Or how does one pass multiple conditions in filter clause?

```
df2 = df.filter((df.dropoff_longitude >= -65.09)&(df.dropoff_longitude <= -63.000))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the pyspark [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter)

you could either use df.filter or df.where to pass filtering condition
for your example to pass multiple conditions

```
df.filter("dropoff_longitude >= -65.09 and df.dropoff_longitude <= -63.000")
df.where("dropoff_longitude >= -65.09 and df.dropoff_longitude <= -63.000")  # SQL String
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.filter(col("dropoff_longitude) >= -65.09) & (col(dropoff_longitude) <= -63.000))
```

speaking for show.

```
df.dropoff_longitude.show()  # this reports an error
df.select("dropoff_longitude").show()  # this line works
```

as .show is a property/function of spark.sql.dataframe instead of spark.sql.columns

so if your transformation returns spark column, then .show won't work
but if your transformation returns to another dataframe, then .show should work